# Strange bug with Catalan number generator

Tags: java, numbers, generator, long-integer, catalan

I'm trying to write a iterative catalan number generator as opposed to a recursive one.  It works, but only up until the number "10", and then it starts to print out numbers that don't make sense.  Here's what I have so far.

```
  public static long dpr1(int n)
  {
  long [] Array = new long[(2*n)+1];

  Array[0]=1;

  Array[1]=1;

  int count=0;

  long c=0;

  for(int i = 2; i<=(2*n); i++){

      Array[i]=(i)*(Array[i-1]);
      count=i;
  }

   return(((Array[count])/(((Array[n]))*(Array[n])))/(n+1));
```

}

I've been testing it using this as a main:

```
public class CatalanTest  
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  long startTime, endTime, result;
  for (int n = 2; n < 18; n = n + 2) 
{ 
System.out.println(Catalan.dpr1(n));
}}}
```

Which returns

```
 2
 14
 132
 1430
 16796
 -2
 97
 0
```

Which are the corresponding Catalan numbers for the even numbers between 2 and 10, but after that the values don't make a ton of sense and I have no idea why.  Any help sorting this out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this code `A[i]` is equal to `Factorial(i)`. When `n=11`, you calculate Factorial up to `22`, and `Factorial(22)` is larger than the max value of long, so your calculations overflow, and the result is wrong.

You can avoid the overflow is you realize that:

```
(Array[count] / (Array[n]*Array[n])) / (n+1) =
 ((2*n)!/(n!*n!))/(n+1) =
 ((n+1)*(n+2)*...*(2n)/(n!))/(n+1)=
 (n+2)*(n+3)*...*(2n)/(n!)
```

So you can forget about your array and just calculate this formula, which would work without overflowing for larger values of n.

Your entire code can be reduced to :

```
    for (long n=2;n<18;n+=2) {
        long res = 1;
        for (long l=n+2;l<=2*n;l++)
           res *= l;
        for (long l=2;l<=n;l++)
           res=res/l;
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Which produces this output (it looks like we still get an overflow for n=16):

```
2
14
132
1430
16796
208012
2674440
91351
```

To avoid that, we can combine the multiplications and divisions, in order to keep the intermediate result small :

```
    for (long n=2;n<18;n+=2) {
        double res = 1;
        for (long l=n+2;l<=2*n;l++) {
           res *= l;
           res /= (l-n);
        }
        System.out.println((long)res);
    }
```

This produces :

```
2
14
132
1430
16796
208012
2674440
35357670
```

Comment: Thank you Eran.  I guess I should have assumed an overflow, but I wasn't sure how to go about fixing it, I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure if people check back on questions they've answered (this is my first post here), but I just wanted to say I'm really impressed by the way you solved my problem @Eran.  
Beyond just pointing out the overflow, the way you go about getting the value of -res- and maintain it's sum without using an array or even a temporary variable is something I never would have come up with.  I'm still relatively new to coding/finding dynamic solutions, but I hope given the time/experience I can get as good at it as you are.  If you have any tips/resources on how I could improve that would be great.